# Replace quotes within quote encapsulated string using Perl regular expressions

Tags: regex, csv, perl, replace

I am trying to replace quotes within a pipe delimited and quote encapsulated file without replacing the quotes providing the encapsulation.

I have tried using the below Perl line to replace the quotes with a back tick ` but am not sure how to replace only the quotes and not the entire group 1.

Sample data (test.txt):

```
"1"|"Text"|"a"\n
"2"|""Text in quotes""|"ab"\n
"3"|"Text "around" quotes"|"abc"\n

perl -pi.bak -e 's/(?<=\|")(.*)(?="\|)/\1`/' test.txt
```

Here is what is happening:

```
"1"|"`"|"a"\n
"2"|"`"|"ab"\n
"3"|"`"|"abc"\n
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
"1"|"Text"|"a"\n
"2"|"`Text in quotes`"|"ab"\n
"3"|"Text `around` quotes"|"abc"\n
```

Comment: I'm surprised you don't want `"3"|"Text ""around"" quotes"|"abc"\n` (proper CSV for `3`, `Text "around" quotes` and `abc`) instead of clobbering your text.

Comment: You didn't define how to handle text that contains `\``

Comment: Grasshopper, once you are back, please let us know how you want to represent *literal* backticks in your fields. In short, if you have ``"2"|""Text `in` quotes""|"ab"``, what should it look like? Should `in` be enclosed with a double backticks? Or escaped with a backslash?  Or any other way?

Comment: @ikegami I am loading this data into a database using SQL*Loader and was fearful that  text such as ""around"" would break the load.  If it works this would be preferrable.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and @ikegami literal backticks in the fields should be enclosed in `` double backticks.

Comment: See [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563967/3832970) with an [online demo](https://ideone.com/LqIdYQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**   for clarification that backticks that are already present should be doubled

---

One way is to `split` on `|` and strip the enclosing quotes to make the remaining  regex simple, then assemble the string back.  That may lose some efficiency in comparison with a single regex but is much simpler to maintain

```
perl -F"\|" -wlanE'
    say join "\|", 
        map { s/^"|"$//g; s/`/``/g; s/"([^"]+)"/`$1`/g; qq("$_") } @F
' data.txt
```

The `-a` option makes it "autosplit" each line so in the program the line tokens are available in `@F`, and the `-F` specifies the pattern to split on (other than default). The `-l` handles newlines. See [Command switches in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches).

In the `map` the enclosing `"`s are removed and any existing backticks doubled; then `"` around patterns are changed, globally. Then the quotes are put back and the returned list `join`-ed. The `|` in the `join` is escaped so to sneak it through the shell to the Perl program; if this goes into a script (instead of a one-liner), what I'd always recommend, change that `\|` to `|`.

I don't know the typical data and possible edge cases regarding quoting, but if there may be loose (single, unpaired) quotes the above will have problems and may produce wrong output, and quietly; just as any procedure that expects paired quotes would, without an extremely detailed analysis.

It may be overall safer to simply replace all `"`s (other than enclosing ones), with

```
map { s/^"|"$//g; s/`/``/g; s/"/`/g; qq("$_") }
```

(or with `tr` instead of regex `s///g`).  That also adds some measure of efficiency.

---

Another way to get to the "meat" of the data is to use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV), which allows a delimiter other than (the default) comma and absorbs the enclosing quotes. Having quotes inside fields is considered bad CSV but the module can parse that just fine as well, with choices below.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Text::CSV;

my $file = shift || 'data.txt';
my $outfile = 'new_' . $file;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { 
    binary => 1, sep_char => '|', 
    allow_loose_quotes => 1, escape_char => '',     # quotes inside fields
    always_quote => 1                               # output as desired
} ) or die "Can't do CSV: ", Text::CSV->error_diag;

open my $fh,     '<', $file    or die "Can't open $file: $!";
open my $out_fh, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    s/`/``/g for @$row;
    tr/"/`/  for @$row;
    $csv->say($out_fh, $row);
}
```

To work with quotes inside fields the `escape_char` needs to differ from `quote_char`; I've simply set it to `''` here. The output is handled by the module as well, and `always_quote` attribute is for that (to quote all fields, needed or not). Please see documentation.

If the purpose of the question is precisely to clean up a file format where same quoting is used both for fields and inside the fields, I'd suggest to do it all with the module. This approach allows one to cleanly and consistently set up all kinds of options, both for input and output, and is maintainable.

---

A few questions

- What kind of data is there and is it possible to have a stray quote? Then what? This can affect even the choice of the optimal approach as it may require a detailed analysis.
- If the quest here is to straighten CSV-style data, then why not double the quotes inside fields, as common and proper in CSV, instead of replacing them (and potentially hurting their textual meaning)? See module's docs, for instance.

Comment: Note that split and multiple regexes don't necessarily lose efficiency when compared to a more complicated single regex. If you really care, you should benchmark them.

Comment: @Grinnz  Corrrect! At first I had "may lose" ... but then, in this case, against a _well written regex_, it should lose "some" I think.  Indeed, should benchmark.  ... actually, I put back that "may".  thanks

Comment: Split could match a pipe contained within a quote encapsulated string.

Comment: @robartsd Well ... there are various possibilities with data that would torpedo any processing.  In this problem a pipe can't be where it shouldn't be, or we should consider the separator to be `"|"` -- and this is possible as well (and could be the pattern for the separator in `split`).  It depends on what real data is like and the OP may need refinements to any approach we offer.

Comment: You should mention how you decided to handle text that already contains `\``.

Comment: @ikegami heh, no decision but just picked up theirs.  It does need a good mention, thank you.  Edited

Answer (score 3):

With Perl 5.14 and newer, you may use

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/(?:^|\|)(")?\K(.*?)(?=\1(?:$|\|))/$2=~s#"|(`)#`$1#gr/ge' test.txt
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lqeAGR/1) and an [online demo](https://ideone.com/LqIdYQ).

The point here is that you match the fields with the first regex, and then you deal with double quotation marks and backticks using the second regex run on the match part.

**Details**

- `(?:^|\|)` - matches the start of a string or `|`
- `(")?` - an optional Group 1 matching  a `"`
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text in the current match buffer
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `(?=\1(?:$|\|))` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is the same value as in Group 1 and then the end of string or `|` immediately to the right of the current location.

So, Group 2 is the cell contents, with no enclosing double quotation marks. `$2=~s#"|(`)#`$1#gr` replaces all `"` with `` ` `` and duplicates all found literal backticks in Group 2 value (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lqeAGR/2)). The `` "|(`) `` pattern matches a `"` or a backtick (capturing the latter into Group 1) and the `` `$1 `` replaces the match with a backtick and the contents of Group 1.

Comment: You should mention how you decided to handle text that already contains `\``.

Comment: @ikegami There is no way to add that to the answer since OP has not provided any specs regarding how to represent literal backticks inside the fields (escaped with another backtick? A backslash?). It can be easily fixed once the specs are revealed.

Comment: That's my point. You made an assumption but didn't document it. What did you assume the OP's spec says concerning this?

Comment: @ikegami Now, it works as expected. Literal backticks [must be doubled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563150/replace-quotes-within-quote-encapsulated-string-using-perl-regular-expressions?noredirect=1#comment95950700_54563150).

Answer (score 1):

Perl uses $1 as the placeholder for the first capturing group in the replacement part of the regex instead of \1 (used in the matching part of the regex). Your regex wasn't matching the inner quotes and would fail to match the first or last field of your pipe delimited data. Your substitution also failed to include a quote character before the captured group.

Try:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/(?<=(?:^|\|)")"([^"]*)"(?="(?:$|\|))/`$1´/' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Perl. After splitting by array @F, check for " that is not at the beginning/end of the elements.

```
 perl -F"\|"  -lane   ' for(@F) { s/(?<!^)"(?!$)/`/g }; print join("|",@F) '
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat grasshopper.txt
"1"|"Text"|"a"
"2"|""Text in quotes""|"ab"
"3"|"Text "around" quotes"|"abc"
$  perl -F"\|"  -lane   ' for(@F) { s/(?<!^)"(?!$)/`/g }; print join("|",@F) ' grasshopper.txt
"1"|"Text"|"a"
"2"|"`Text in quotes`"|"ab"
"3"|"Text `around` quotes"|"abc"
$
```